# Most effecient way to compute a series of moves in peg solitaire

Tags: language-agnostic, dynamic-programming, game-theory

Given an arbitary peg solitaire board configuration, what is the most effecient way to compute any series of moves that results in the "end game" position.

For example, the standard starting position is:

```
..***..
..***..
*******
***O***
*******
..***..
..***..
```

And the "end game" position is:

```
..OOO..
..OOO..
OOOOOOO
OOO*OOO
OOOOOOO
..OOO..
..OOO..
```

Peg solitare is described in more detail here: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peg_solitaire), we are considering the "english board" variant.

I'm pretty sure that it is possible to solve any given starting board in just a few secconds on a reasonable computer, say an P4 3Ghz.

Currently this is my best strategy:

```
def solve:
    for every possible move:
        make the move.
        if we haven't seen a rotation or flip of this board before:
            solve()
            if solved: return
        undo the move.
```

Comment: Is this homework, or an interview question?

Comment: @Nathon I'm in seccondary school, this is neither homework nor interview question. Just something I dug up that I find currious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wikipedia article you link to already mentions that there only 3,626,632 possible board positions, so it it easy for any modern computer to do an exhaustive search of the space.

Your algorithm above is right, the trick is implementing the "haven't seen a rotation or flip of this board before", which you can do using a hash table. You probably don't need the "undo the move" line as a real implementation would pass the board state as an argument to the recursive call so you would use the stack for storing the state.

Also, it is not clear what you might mean by "efficient".

If you want to find all sequences of moves that lead to a winning stage then you need to do the exhaustive search.

If you want to find the shortest sequence then you could use a branch-and-bound algorithm to cut off some search trees early on. If you can come up with a good static heuristic then you could try A* or one of its variants.

Comment: I only want to find 1 path, and it can be any length. Also, in Peg Solitaire all solutions are nessisarily the same length.

Currently I'm using a python list with unique board identifiers to check if the board has been seen. And as I'm using Python, passing by reference, I think I need to undo the move, especially as I've designed by Board class to be rather ineffecient to create, but very quick to alter.

Comment: Oh, well, if all solutions are the same length (I can see why now, every move takes away a peg) then branch and bound is out, unless you find some heuristic that says "from this state it is impossible to reach a solution". I think that should exist, right? I can't think of one...

Comment: I found on some papers what is referred to as a *Pagoda function*. It's supposed to tell if a board state is winnable or not, but I don't really understand how to apply it.

Comment: @thomasfedb that is not exactly true. Some game methods allow a move to keep going so long as the same peg can keep jumping. In this case you could have solutions with different lengths. The shortest obviously being the optimal. The English board takes 31 moves if you only allow one move per jump but it can be done in 18 moves if you allow multiple jumps per move.

Answer (score 0):

Start from the completed state, and walk backwards in time. Each move is a hop that leaves an additional peg on the board.

At every point in time, there may be multiple unmoves you can make, so you'll be generating a tree of moves. Traverse that tree (either depth-first or breadth-) stopping any branch when it reaches the starting state or no longer has any possible moves. Output the list of paths that led to the original starting state.

Comment: This is the exact inverse of the original problem, AFAIK it doesn't reduce its complexity.